# Jest - How do you test a state property has changed with Styled components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, styled-components

Struggling to understand how I can test a component that has been made by a styled component.

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Picker from '../CurrencyPicker';

describe('Test Language/Currency Dropdown', () => {
  it('On Click open the dropddown menu and check that the state is true.', () => {
    const output = shallow(<Picker />);

    expect(output.state().dropdown).toEqual(false);
    output.simulate('click');
    expect(output.state().dropdown).toEqual(true);
  });
});
```

So this is my test I simply want to check if the state dropdown changes from false to true from the picker component below:

```
const NavLinkContainer = styled.span`
  &:focus { outline: none; }
`;

export default class CurrencyPicker extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = { dropdown: false };

  this.toggleDropdown = this.toggleDropdown.bind(this);
}

toggleDropdown(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  this.setState({
    dropdown: !this.state.dropdown,
  });
}

render() {
  return (
    <NavLinkContainer
      onClick={this.toggleDropdown}
      role="menuitem"
      tabIndex="0"
    >
      test
    </NavLinkContainer>
  );
 }
}
```

I thought if I simulate a click on the component that it'll know I'll be talking about the only click event in the component.

From looking at other tests it looks like I'm meant to use the **find()** to get to NavLinkContainer.

So something like:

```
const link = wrapper.find('NavLinkContainer')
```

And then simulate the click on the link instead of the wrapper. I don't get any luck with either solutions. I'm wondering if having styled components is causing me a problem with the tests that I wouldn't normally get or more likely I am missing something from the documentation.

Ta

Comment: Don't test across component boundaries. All you need to test here is that is that if you set state `dropdown: true`, then the right thing is rendered. You could also test that on render the onClick method is passed down correctly to the child prop

Comment: Is it possible to give an example of what you mean?